# I can't add fields to my registration form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I never had this problem before, but I am trying to add a field to my registration form from **FOSUserBundle**. In results I have only the default form from the bundle and didn't get my `birthday_date` field. What am I doing wrong?

**RegistrationType class:**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('birthday_date');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
}
```

**config.yml:**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            name: app_user_registration
```

**services.yml**:

```
app.form.registration:
    class: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: app_user_registration }
```

I just follow the document instructions so i have no idea, where's the problem

Comment: In your config, if you change `name` to `type` under registration: form:  does that get you anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getParent()` function should return the class of the parent form and not the name, these changes comes with versions > 2.8, check [Overriding a Form Type](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html#overriding-a-form-type)

So your form type class should become:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;


class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('birthday_date');
}
public function getParent()
{
    return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
}
public function getName()
{
    return 'app_user_registration';
}
}
```

Comment: That's what i had to do. But documentation also says about change in config.yml. We have to change `name: app_user_registration` to `type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationType`